# Deleting an EF Core entity ONLY if it's no longer referenced by parents

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Say I have a table called `Address` which is referenced by `Order`, `Person` and `Supplier`.

Let's say I have a method `UpdateOrderAddress` that changes the order's address:

```cs
public async Task UpdateOrderAddress(int orderId, Address newAddress) {
    var order = await context.Order.FindAsync(orderId);
    var oldAddress = order.Address; /* Keep this so that we can try and delete it */
    order.Address = newAddress;
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I want to delete the old address ONLY if it's no longer referenced by any other table. One way to do this is by manually checking every single table that references `Address`:

```cs
public async Task UpdateOrderAddress(int orderId, Address newAddress) {
    var order = await context.Order.FindAsync(orderId);
    var oldAddress = order.Address; /* Keep this so that we can try and delete it */
    order.Address = newAddress;

    IQueryable[] tables = [context.Order, context.Person, context.Supplier];

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    if (!tables.Any(table => table.Any(obj => obj.AddressId == oldAddress.AddressId)) 
    {
        context.Address.Remove(oldAddress);
    }
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This not only seems tedious, but also hard to maintain and also inefficient in the scenario where there's a large number of tables that reference Address (as in my real life scenario).

Another option would be a `try-catch`, however it seems more dangerous as I'd have to catch a `SqlException`, compare the code, which would be thrown for any foreign key error:

```cs
try 
{
    context.Address.Remove(oldAddress);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
} 
catch (SqlException ex) 
{
    if (ex.Number != 547) 
        throw ex;
}
```

Is there a solution better than these two?

Comment: How exactly does `Address` reference a parent?

Comment: I don't think you'll find much better than try/catch, the SQL engine will almost certainly determine if relationships exist quicker than any code you can write. But in terms of a better solution, have you considered just not deleting the address? I personally would want to know for audit purposes if an address on an order had been changed, and to know what it had been changed from I'd need to retain the old address, even if the order no longer references it. Unless the building has actually been demolished and the address no longer exists then I can't see any harm in retaining it.

Comment: Even if it has been demolished I'd be inclined to do a Soft delete because I'd still want to know that it once existed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new(-ish) [`ExecuteDeleteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#executeupdate-and-executedelete-bulk-updates) to do a joined `DELETE` directly on the database.

You need a transaction if you want to ensure atomicity of the whole operation, and you need to detach the entity if you are going to use or save the context after this.

```cs
public async Task UpdateOrderAddress(int orderId, Address newAddress)
{
    using var tran = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAync();

    var order = await context.Order.FindAsync(orderId);
    var oldAddress = order.Address; /* Keep this so that we can try and delete it */
    order.Address = newAddress;
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var rowsAffected = context.Address
        .Where(a =>
            a.Id == oldAddress.Id
            && !a.Orders.Any()
            && !a.Persons.Any()
            && !a.Suppliers.Any()
        .ExecuteDeleteAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(rowsAffected == 0 ? "nothing deleted" : "address deleted");

    await tran.CommitAsync();
    context.Entry(oldAddress).State = EntityState.Detached;   // detach the entity without saving
}
```